# DataFlow Template Operator fail in Airflow / Composer due to empty tempLocation

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to run a DataFlow job from an Airflow DAG using a DataflowTemplateOperator.

My Dataflow job is based on a template generated from a Google Cloud Dataprep job which read a GCS file and load it into a BigQuery table.
This Dataflow job runs OK when launched from Dataprep but failed when lauched in Airflow with following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.parseScheme(FileSystems.java:443)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchNewResource(FileSystems.java:529)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers.resolveTempLocation(BigQueryHelpers.java:350)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads$4.getTempFilePrefix(BatchLoads.java:390)
```

When I check the Dataflow console, I effectively detect a difference between both execution on org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions.tempLocation parameters:

- "gs://..." when executed with Dataprep
- "-" when executed with Airflow DataflowTemplateOperator.

Even using dataflow_default_options in my dag configuration, I'm not able to modify it to avoid this "-" (empty?) value.

Any idea about how to run properly this Dataflow template in Airflow ?

Comment: Have you found answer?